# on click long implementation when onClick is already in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have actually read several answers to this but they are so different than the simple way I am implementing click responses that I am wondering if there is a way to add something simple to what I am doing to create an onLongClick responas.

Basically, all my XML code is written with statements like this:

```
android:onClick="onSync"
```

Then my Java has:

```
    public void onSync(View v) {
            ...
        Toast toast3=Toast.makeText(this, "Sync was pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast3.show();
    }
```

What I would like to do is have a different function that is called when the button gets a long press.  Right now, a long press causes the same action as a short press.

Specifically, I would like to know how to interface to a routine such as this:

```
        public void onSyncLong(View v) {
            ...
        Toast toast3=Toast.makeText(this, "Long Sync was pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast3.show();
    }
```

I would certainly appreciate any help on this problem.  It would be great if the reply told me what to do in the XML and in the Jave.  Thanks so much.

----------------------------UPDATE------------------------

Here is my onCreate code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_meters);

    textLL = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLL);
    textTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
    textTimeToLine = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimeToLine);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sync);

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });

}
```

And here is the button XML segment

```
        <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSync"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Gun/Sync" 
    android:onClick="onSync"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_small"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:padding="3sp"
    android:longClickable="true"/>
```

------------Final Update----------------

Here is the working code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_meters);

    textLL = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLL);
    textTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
    textTimeToLine = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimeToLine);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSync);

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                StartLine2.startTime = pTime + 1000*60*5;
                return true;
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this via XML. Instead, use:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.<your_id>);

button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Make sure this code comes after `setContentView()` has been called.

Also, make sure that the `android:longClickable` property is set to true.

In your XML, the ID is set to `buttonSync`, while in the Java code you're using `button_sync`. This is the reason for your `NullPointerException`, as you don't have a button called `button_sync`.

Comment: Perhaps I need a little more context as all I got was errors. I got <your_id> in correctly but I am not sure where this code goes relative to the code I posted.  Eclipse ended up doing something strange and deleting all my last 5 versions so I can't post any code...  Working on recreating my code right now.

Comment: Let me just add, this may be wonderful code but without knowing where to put it, if it is complete, it is very frustrating.  There are many examples of code for long press in Stockoverflow but they all suffer from this, imho.  The official Android documentation is very complete with either doesn't run, or has no examples.

Comment: This code is like any other .setXXX() method. The first line can be called anytime after setContentView(), and the second part comes anytime (usually immediately) after it. Personally, I usually put it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  My code does not have setContentView() so I guess I need to research that. I did try the code in onCreate() but perhaps lacking setContentView() is what caused the errors.

Comment: How are you drawing your layout? If it's from an XML file, then there has to be a setContentView() somewhere. If it's dynamically created, then simply use the same Button object you use to create the button. But since you mentioned XML in your code, I answered assuming that.

Comment: Oops, I do have setContentView  I guess I had a type when I searched for it.  I get two errors. "Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new 
  OnLongClickListener(){})"  That error is on the button line.  There is another error on the line starting with public but I always try and fix the first error first.

Comment: Make sure your imports are correct. Hover over the error line, and it'll suggest importing a class. Do that, and the error should go away.

Comment: OK, progress.  No compile errors but I get a null pointer exception when I run the activity even before pressing any buttons.

Comment: Most likely, button is null. Could you post your onCreate() method?

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  In my defense, I did't type button_sync,I let Eclipse auto fill it. I should have checked it though.  In any event, my code is now working. I will edit a second update.  You have been most helpful.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GameScoreFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.v("TTT", "GameScoreFragment.OnCreateView()");

        View viewScore = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gamescorelayout, container, false);


        // set onLongClick listeners for both buttons
        // when player long presses any of the two buttons, scores are reset

        Button tempButton = (Button) viewScore.findViewById(R.id.id_button_pone_score);
        tempButton.setOnLongClickListener( mLongListener );

        tempButton = (Button) viewScore.findViewById(R.id.id_button_ptwo_score);
        tempButton.setOnLongClickListener( mLongListener );

        return viewScore;
    }


    // define a variable mLongListener to hold the listener code
    // and then use mLongListener to set the listener
    // if we don't define the variable, then we will have to write the listener code at two places (once for each button)

    private View.OnLongClickListener mLongListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View pView) {
            //reset player scores
            GameFragment tempGameFragment = (GameFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.id_gamefragment);
            if (tempGameFragment != null)
                tempGameFragment.resetPlayersScore(false);

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```